# Xcode storyboard versus @3x

Tags: xcode, storyboard, retina-display

Using storyboard on Xcode 6.  I have 3 images

bkg_menu_iphone@3x.png,
bkg_menu_iphone@2x.png,
bkg_menu_iphone.png

Xcode automatically detect the regular and @2x(merge it together in the Media view, etc), but the @3x stay alone.

1. Any idea why Xcode still not manage the @3x?
2. My first idea was to have ONLY the @3x and have xcode auto adjust size based on the device.  But it doesnt work well using the storyboard. (If I drag it to the viewcontroller, it was not auto resize as a @2x or other.) (and if I use the @2x, it was)
3. How do you manage the 3 iPhone size versus storyboard?

Hope my english was ok.  Thanks for comment & best practice.

[image: Xcode 6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Xcode 6.3.1.  You should use Images.xcassets found in the File Manager.

[image]

You then drag and drop the images from the File Manger into the left hand pane of the Images.xcassets.  It will create a new xcasset with the same name minus the @#x.png.

[image]

You then drag the other resolution files and drop the into the corresponding image placeholders.

[image]

You can then use the name of the .xcasset in the storyboard as shown below.

[image]

(pick the first entry without the .png extension)